# How to print out the full value of a variable in Hugo

Tags: hugo

I am using [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) to generate my static site.
I have to inspect the value of a variable in Hugo to make sure I get expected results. Consider the following in `index.html`:

```
{{ $pages := .Pages }}
<body>
  <div> {{ $pages }} </div>
</body>
```

What I get is:

```
Pages(3)
```

But what I want is to see the full serialized value of the object. How to achieve it?

---

#### Attempts

I have tried:

```
<div> {{ print $pages }} </div>
```

However still the same.

Answer (score 5):

You have `printf` available, so you can try

```
{{ printf "%#v" $pages }}
```

[Hugo template debugging](https://gohugo.io/templates/template-debugging/)